# sm-level : 1.3 vs 2.0 performance

Tags: performance, cuda

My code doesn't depend on sm level. I can build it with sm10, If I want. But when I tried to build it with 1.3 instead of 2.0, as I did it before, I got x1.25 performance with no code changes!
 sm20 -> 35ms
 sm13 -> 25ms

After that gorgeous results, I tried to box/unbox every option in project settings->CUDA settings->*all* :) I guess, I found the stuff, which made that awesome speed:

- If I use sm13 with "no fast math generation" (further fm - fast
  math), I have 25ms
- If I use sm13 with fm, I have 25ms
- sm20 without fm = 35ms
- sm20 with fm = 25ms (that is the same result)

Why is this so? Maybe sm13 forces using hardware maths, but sm20 not? Or it is only coincidence, and the latter sm level have lower performance, refer to lower sm level programs?

Comment: Are you using visual studio?  If so are you compiling debug or release version of project?

Comment: Yes, visual studio. I tested both (13 and 20) with debug version. Is it so important in my problem? :O

Comment: If you want GPU code to run fast, you should not use debug version.  The `-G` switch used in debug version often makes GPU code run slower.

Comment: I know it of course, but I still debug it, because it hasn't finished yet. That 25ms:35ms feature I found by accident, but I wanna know, why is this so?

p.s Tried compile it in release version now for test and get "fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined"... Main function defined of course. In debug version all works well. The second question (appears) is what's going on with release?

Comment: The seconds question is deprecated :) Build it up in release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to compiling in release mode, as pointed out by @Robert Crovella, you should also consider that when you target sm_13 the compiler is able to simplify some of the floating point maths. sm_20 and later supports precise division, precise square root, and denormals by default.

You can try disabling these features with the command line options `-ftz=true -prec-div=false -prec-sqrt=false`. See the [best practices guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#precision-related-compiler-flags) for more information.